# Deduce the return type of an abstract class method

Tags: c++, c++17, abstract-class

I want to deduce a return type for a method of an abstract class

```
class A {
public:
    int foo();
    virtual void other() = 0;
};
```

`foo` is a method that can be changed by another person. Specifically, it's return type can change to some other type.

At my point I want to write something like

```
using Foos_Return_Type = decltype(A().foo());
```

But A is abstract, and I can't get this `int` out.

What is the approach to extract the return type for a method of an abstract class?

Comment: did you forget `virtual` ?

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::declval`, how it works, and know how to use it?

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<A&>().foo())`?